# Google Cloud Storage returning 403 for user present in ACL

Tags: oauth, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a google cloud bucket where I want to give individual users permission to access individual files. So I have a file with the uri: `gs://my-bucket/my-file` and on the ACL list for that object, I have `myuser@gmail.com` listed as a "user" with "read" permissions.

However, any attempt to access that file using the url: 
`https://storage.cloud.google.com/my-bucket/myfile` through the browser returns a short page stating `403 forbidden` even though I am logged in. If I open an incognito tab, I am prompted to log in to google when I go to that URL, but once I have finished the login, I get the same `403` message.

With the same credentials I can easily download the file using gsutil, or from the google developers console. But I can't seem to download it with an authenticated user from a web link.

EDIT: To be clear, this object is not meant to be *public*, it should only be accessible to project owner/editors and any person specifically named in the objects ACL. I am going off of [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/cookie-based-authentication) document.

EDIT2: This is the entry for the user in the object's ACL

```
{
    "email": "myuser@gmail.com",
    "entity": "user-myuser@gmail.com",
    "role": "READER"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to also provide bucket [permission](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions?hl=en_US) to that user.

Comment: What role should I give them so that they don't have access to *every* file in the bucket, only that *one* file?